# How does one convert a Grayscale image to RGB channels in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have a grayscale image in OpenCV represented by:

```
cv::Mat img_grayscale;
```

It has one channel (0-255). I want to convert it into an RGB image where for each pixel, R=G=B=(0-255).

For the record: I am NOT trying to convert it to color; but, I want to be able to overlay it with colored text/images. So I need a grayscale image with RGB channels.

Comment: That seems like the easiest conversion ever; just create an RGB image of the same size and set R, G, and B to the gray value of each pixel.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's what I need to do. I just can't seem to figure out how to edit the cv::Mat per pixel.

Comment: have you tried to google it? `cvtColor`